# scale and change the color of a svg on hover in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have the following custom Icon component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Icon = (props: any) => {
  const styles = {
    svg: {
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
    },
    path: {
       fill: props.color,
    },
  };

  return (

    <svg

      style={styles.svg}
      width={`${props.size}px`}
      height={`${props.size}px`}
      viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
    >
       <path style={styles.path} d={props.icon} /> 
    </svg>
  );


};

Icon.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.number,
  color: PropTypes.string

};

Icon.defaultProps = {
  size: 16
};

export default Icon
```

In another component I instantiate it with the following statement:

```
<Icon
          icon={ICONS.TWITTER}
          color="#fff"
          size={30}
        />
```

How can I change the size and color on hover?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to do this in Javascript or with CSS?

Comment: preferably with Css

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you want to solve this using React, you need to make the component that is rendering your `<Icon />` component and setting its props aware of wether the `<Icon />` component is hovered or not.

This means that the parent component has to become stateful and the `<Icon />` component needs to implement some kind of callback when the mouse enters and leaves it. For this, you could use the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` functions ([see the docs as well](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events)). These would then just set a boolean flag in the state of the parent component, and based on this, the props would change.

An implementation could look like this:

```
<Icon
  icon={ICONS.TWITTER}
  color={this.state.isHovered ? '#333' : '#fff'}
  size={this.state.isHovered ? 40 : 30}
  onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
  onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
/>
```

Where `handleMouseEnter()` could look like this:

```
handleMouseEnter = () => {
  this.setState({ isHovered: true })
}
```

and `handleMouseLeave()` would just do the opposite.

**Note though**, that this is a lot of work to implement something that browsers already do for you (the `:hover` state in CSS), so it is worth considering if you need the effect to be as dynamic as it now is, or if you could just live with a fixed increase in size and color change.
Also, `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` can cause some issues with touch devices.

Comment: This is one of the ways I used the same approach in my code but is there a way to change it without using the state, because we are using a lot of memory resources to change a simple color, this has to be done in CSS...

Comment: Sure, this is also possible using CSS only (and it probably is the preferable way to do it because of the reasons you listed). Size change on hover should be straight forward and changing the color probably would come down to having `fill: currentColor` on the svg and setting the `color` of the parent element on hover.

Comment: I actually did something like that, but since I used style as React component the problem was I had to add ' & path': { fill: color} :)